# "Operation is not supported on this platform" using excel interop component

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, excel-interop

i'm trying to migrate simple .net framework application that is using microsoft.office.interop.excel to .net core but from the start using the function Worksheet.QueryTables keep getting the error - Operation is not supported on this platform

```
using IExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

            IExcel.Application excelApp = new IExcel.Application();
            IExcel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            IExcel.Worksheet ws;
            IExcel.Range range;
            wb = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
            ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            range = ws.get_Range("A1");
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            IExcel.QueryTable QT = ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" + csvFilefullpath, range);
```

any idea what is wrong?

Thanks,
Y

Comment: I’m pretty sure interop only works on .NET framework. Happy to be proven wrong. The nuget info shows only support for .NET framework … https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/

Comment: I took your tip and just running on .net framework.i guess the work around is using nuget excel object related